# SAML 2.0 integration with Angular 6

Tags: angular, authentication, saml-2.0

I have separate an angular-6 application and i need to use **SAML 2.0** as authentication in that, so Is it possible to do so? I didn't find any relevant example on google

Comment: did you find a solution? is it possible?